# Line Item still delivering even though it is set to not appear on page via key values

Tags: google-ad-manager

I am trying to exclude a line item from showing in an ad slot using key-values.  This is working across the site with other Line Items as expected.  However on one particular line item this doesn't work, the item is still delivering and winning despite the exclusion.  This was originally set a few days a go so cannot be just a delay on ad managers side.

If I run the Simulation for the Ad Slot it never shows as a winning line item, but in reality it does.

[Image showing Excluded LI winning bid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYEle.png)

I have re-created the Line Item from scratch and the problem persists.  If I run a report on the Ad Unit only the expected Line Item shows up in name, but there is another unnamed Line Item delivering impressions.

[Report showing Line Items delivering on Ad Unit, the excluded Line Item does not show on the report in name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aArrf.png)

Answer (score 0):

A dash "-" for the line item name could indicate that it's not an actual line item which won the impression, but rather [First Look](https://support.google.com/admanager/answer/6300696?hl=en) or [Exchange Bidding](https://support.google.com/admanager/answer/7128453?hl=en)/[Mediation](https://support.google.com/admanager/answer/7391294?hl=en). I would recommend you add the "Demand Channel" dimension to your report (details [here](https://support.google.com/admanager/table/7531695)), to find out who is winning the impression.

1. If the line item name is "-" and demand channel is Ad Exchange, then the impression might have been won by First Look.
2. If instead demand channel is Exchange Bidding or Mediation, then what's winning it's an Yield group, in which case you should add the Yield group dimension to the report, to find out which one of them is winning.